# Location of network configuration files AlmaLinux 9

Tags: networkmanager, alma-linux

I'm a bit confussed with NetworkManager in AlmaLinux 9. I'm using VPS from Linode. I have created a VPS with one Ethernet interface with public IP. Its configuration file is stored in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`. Then I have added another ethernet interface without public IP connected to VLAN. When I have configured it's IP with `nmcli` it have saved it's configuration in
`/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/eth1.nmconnection`.

Can You tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*` is the RedHat style backwards-compatible way to store network configuration settings.

`/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*.nmconnection` is NetworkManager's native, distribution-agnostic way to do the same.

The developers of NetworkManager apparently hope that eventually all distributions using NetworkManager would converge to use their way of storing network settings, but they recognize that there is a lot of existing automation/integration code that relies on the classic, distribution-specific ways to store network configuration settings; for example, the Linode VPS management web UI might be one of those. So the convergence might be very slow or not happen at all.

So, NetworkManager has a plugin-based system for network configuration storage. Each distribution can create their own plug-in to at least read their previous network configuration storage, and optionally write to it too if the distribution is not trying to achieve a transition to NetworkManager's native configuration style.

Also, various desktop environments use the same plug-in mechanism to provide a way to store network configuration settings (e.g. VPN settings) per-user, using the desktop environment's own mechanism (e.g. GNOME Keyring, KDE Wallet) for storing the settings (which may include passwords) securely.

Linode might even had the NetworkManager on their VPSs set up intentionally that way to make their support personnel's job easier: if the settings created by the VPS management web GUI go to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*` and the customer's own customizations go to `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`, then it becomes easy to provide an automated way to disable the customer's customizations and restore the basic network configuration to the VPS, if the customer has accidentally made their VPS inaccessible. It might be implemented as a tool for Linode's support personnel, or even provided as a customer self-help function in their VPS management web GUI.